# download file from database by file's path

Tags: asp.net, download

I had a download task in my project, which inserts files and downloads these files.  I did my table in database and have a column which has the path of file and folder in project which will have the files.  I did this well and my files insert well in folder and path in database.  But I could not download these files from folder with the ID of path from database.  Please help me to do that.

Comment: Please share some relevant code.  It's hard to know what to recommend without knowing the context you are working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u checked that when u are saving the url of the uploaded file in ur database u have used the format  ~//some_directory//filename.extension

if u have not wrote it like ~//blabla//blabla.bla   it wont work